# Upgraded Python on Snowleopard Using Homebrew now pip and easy_install don't work

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I am new to python, I have changed my path to point to the new python 2.7, but pip and easy_install, and mercurial are still looking at the default installed version 2.6. How do I fix this?

Comment: Thanks, that did it, still need to change the path to the homebrew directory. For anyone else who finds this.

Comment: Joey: I still have the same problem... can you elaborate shortly on that part? (i.e. change the path to the homebrew directory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to re-install easy_install using Python 2.7 and all other modules as well. Don't expect that existing packages installed with a different interpreter are supposed to work out of the box with a new interpreter. Reinstalling into the new Python 2.7 interpreter is the way to go. First step: reinstall easy_install by downloading ez_setup.py (Google) and running it with the 2.7 interpreter..

Answer (score 5):

You need to install `pip` and `setuptools` again (which provides the `easy_install` command) for your new version of Python. `pip` and `setuptools` are not globally installed, rather they must be installed specifically for each version of Python on your system.

To install `pip`:

```
$ curl -O https://github.com/pypa/pip/raw/master/contrib/get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py
```

To install `setuptools`:

```
$ curl -O http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
$ python ez_setup.py
```

… but you should probably be using [Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) (it's a newer version of `setuptools`):

```
$ curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
$ python distribute_setup.py
```

Comment: For those who stumble across this answer today (2 years later), I would `curl -O -L https://github.com/pypa/pip/raw/master/contrib/get-pip.py` (-L is 'follow http redirect')