# Why is Python easy_install not working on my Mac?

Tags: python, macos, easy-install

I have a Mac running Python 2.6. When I try to use `easy_install` I get this message:

```
/usr/bin/easy_install-2.6:7: UserWarning: Module pkg_resources was already imported from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.pyc, but /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages is being added to sys.path
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
/usr/bin/easy_install-2.6:7: UserWarning: Module site was already imported from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site.pyc, but /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages is being added to sys.path
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.6", line 10, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c9', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 271, in load_entry_point
    return False
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2173, in load_entry_point
    deps = []
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'easy_install') not found
```

I am very confused by this and I want to know how I can fix this. Previously I didn't get this message, then after installing `pip` and uninstalling it, easy_install no longer works. I was wondering how I could fix this, or restore the default Python or easy_install setting on Mac.

Answer (score 155):

1. Check your /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin for easy_install installations and remove any old script:

   ```
   sudo rm -f /usr/bin/easy_install*
   sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/easy_install*
   ```
2. Download and run distribute:

   ```
   curl -O https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/oodt/tools/oodtsite.publisher/trunk/distribute_setup.py

   sudo python distribute_setup.py
   sudo rm distribute_setup.py
   ```
3. Try again, and enjoy. E.g.:

   ```
   sudo easy_install pip
   ```

Comment: These instructions worked perfectly after the Mountain Lion upgrade borked everything. This got easy_install and pip working, which let me upgrade my virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper, and everything's happy again.

Comment: This also worked for me after installing OSX 10.9 Mavericks. Thanks

Comment: I'm gettin "-bash: /usr/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory", I may have forgotten the asterisk at the end, any ideas on how to fix my predicament?

Comment: No worries about that. It means it could not find it there, but there is a possibility you have them on /usr/local/bin... In any case, execute all the commands all over again.

Comment: Use URL `https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/oodt/tools/oodtsite.publisher/trunk/distribute_setup.py` since python-distribute.org isn't up.

Comment: @Jason Any idea why or how long is that going to be for?

Comment: I don't think anything is installed into my `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin/` after running `sudo python distribute_setup.py` because I get `-bash: /usr/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory` error message.

Answer (score 27):

I suspect the easiest way you can get `easy_install` working again is to install [`distribute`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute), which is an improved version of [`distutils`](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html) that bundles it's own version of `easy_install`. Installation is simple:

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
/usr/bin/python2.6 distribute_setup.py
```

Comment: If you're using [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) you can do `sudo brew install distribute`

Comment: It appears that `distribute` now comes with the python recipe, but scripts are put into `/usr/local/share/python/` so you may be picking up an old version of easy_install symlinked in `/usr/local/bin`.  See: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed my Python install problem! pip, easy_install and friends all gave errors after upgrading pip+virtualenv.

Comment: Sounds like the installation of `easy_install` is not easy at all. (shrug)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem just after installing the new Operating System (Lion OSX). 
After install python and execute it

```
sudo easy_install ipython
ipython
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ipython==0.10.2', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2220, in load_entry_point
    raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'ipython') not found
```

Then I realize it was a permission problem. If I execute the ipython script as sudo it worked.

```
sudo ipython
```

So I changed the ownership from root to my user () of the folder /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

```
sudo chown -R <your_user>:wheel /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

Use change ownership only if you don't have several accounts that uses python.

I hope it work for you.

Best

Comment: It's probably a better idea to `chmod` than to `chown` in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Your setuptools installation is broken. The `easy_install-2.6` script in your `/usr/bin` directory, is only a wrapper that loads the actual `easy_install` module in your Python installation, and the latter is missing. Presumably uninstalling `pip` either broke the pointer to it (usually in the form of a `.pth` file in your `site-packages` directory) or removed the whole package but didn't remove the `/usr/bin/easy_install-2.6` wrapper script.

Your best bet is to re-install `setuptools` from scratch again, by following the [instructions on the setuptools PyPI page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#cygwin-mac-os-x-linux-other).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I suspect caused by my installation of Homebrew which apparently installs its own version of easy_install blindly and screws up whatever you're currently running (enough times for homebrew to recognize it as a problem). I found my solution here [Upgraded Python on Snowleopard Using Homebrew now pip and easy_install don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585473/upgraded-python-on-snowleopard-using-homebrew-now-pip-and-easy-install-dont-wor)

While I'm actually on Lion, it still fixed my problem. You just download ez_setup.py from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ez_setup - run ez_setup.py through terminal and you're off to the races.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error message after following similar steps. I suspect it's because I tried to install the distribute module, and it tried to install a new version of setuptools which 
didn't quite work because it failed to correctly override the Mac OS X supplied setuptools. But that's only a suspicion.

I fixed my problem by doing the following. I found that the directory `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python`
had 4 files with .OLD in the name. When I did a compare with similarly named files without the .OLD from when things worked (via Time Machine) I found that they were the same except for the name. So I did the following renames:

> setuptools.OLD.1305936263.57 **->**
>   setuptools
>   setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg-info.OLD.1305936263.57 **->** setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg-info
>  pkg_resources.py.OLD.1305936263.57
>   **->** pkg_resources
>  site.py.OLD.1305936263.59 **->** site.py

I had to use the command line and `sudo mv` because the files are owned by root. For example: `sudo mv setuptools.OLD.1305936263.57 setuptools`. You'll have to enter your password.

The other thing I did was clean the `/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages` directory. I used Time Machine to set it back to its pre-messed up state. If you don't have Time Machine, then you should be able to recover if you delete any files or folders beginning with distribute, easy-install, pip, pkg_resources, setuptools and site.

If that doesn't do the trick, uninstall any modules you can from that directory. For example use `pip uninstall` if you installed modules with pip. The reason to do this is that installation can copy files into `usr/local/bin` and other places that pip will remove for you.

Next it's time to remove any remaining modules. Rename the folder (in case there's something you want later) and make a new empty one.

Reinstall the modules you want and with a little luck you're back in business...

Answer (score 0):

Martijn Pieter's answer is correct.

1. Go to http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads
2. Download `setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg`
3. From your downloads directory run: `sudo ./setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg`

Done :-)

Comment: I have a very similar problem but I had to downgrade setuptools to exactly 0.6c9 that it was asking for. Now I have a gcc error.