# Plone buildout error when using a package created with paster

Tags: plone, setuptools, paster

I'm new to Plone (4.1) and following Martin Aspeli's Professional Plone 4 development book. While following the book to create a custom theme, named optilux.theme (chapter 8), I encounter the following errors: http://pastie.org/3201791

**The first error** is from zopeskel when creating the theme distribution using

```
../bin/zopeskel plone optilux.theme
```

I can, however,  customise the files zopeskel generated as stated in the book (setup.py, configure.zcml, metadata.xml).

**The second error** is from running buildout with the freshly added theme, using http://good-py.appspot.com/release/plone.app.theming/1.0b9 as KGS.

My question is twofold:

1. are the 2 errors related? ie. does the zopeskel error imply buildout will not find the optilux.theme?
2. how can I make buildout find optilux.theme and deploy succesfully?

Version Overview:
Plone 4109
CMF 2.2.4
Zope 2.13.8
Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Aug 11 2011, 12:16:10) [GCC 4.6.1]
PIL 1.1.7

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these two errors are related.

At the line #52 Zopeskel/Paster says that it can't retrieve the 'egg-info' directory and the creation process ends incorrectly.

This is a common issue (tickets [#384](http://trac.pythonpaste.org/pythonpaste/ticket/384) and [#10963](http://dev.plone.org/ticket/10963)).

That issue is linked to a known bug in setuptools versions prior to 0.6c7. Just update your setuptools package to the latest release (`/path/to/your/python/interpreter/easy_install -U setuptools`) and re-start the wizard for creating the package.

**Edit** (this follow the first comment):

Edit your buildout.cfg (or any other *.cfg file that you use as the start point) like this:

```
[buildout]
auto-checkout = 
    ...
    optilux.theme

develop =
    ...
    src/optilux.theme

eggs +=
    ... 
    optilux.theme

[instance]

zcml +=
    ...
    optilux.theme
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was able to update setuptools after a short detour via [another error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6012347/1154391). The zopeskel error subsequently disappeared. 
However, the second error still persists when running buildout: Error: Couldn't find a distribution for 'optilux.theme'. Any thought on how to fix this?

Comment: Take a look at the "edit" part of the answer. If it doesn't help, please add your buildout.cfg in your question so I can take a look on it.

Comment: Ait thanks a million! After some testing I found only the line      develop =
    src/optilux.theme  
was needed to get buildout to run without errors. Would have been helpful to have that explained in the book though. Anyway, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the "can't retrieve the 'egg-info' directory" problem as well.  However, I was using version 0.6c11 of setuptools.  It turned out that I had a broken setuptools module. The package was in my site-packages directory but I could not load it.  A reinstall of my virtualenv python solved the problem.