# easy_install : ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'easy_install') not found

Tags: python, macos, easy-install

I used easy_install to install pip, pip to install django, virtualenv, and virtualenvwrapper.

I have just returned to it a few weeks later and django does not seem to work anymore, but more concerning is I can't start the process over again as easy_install is returning the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7", line 10, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c12dev-r88846', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2220, in load_entry_point
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'easy_install') not found
```

After a good evening of hunting I am stumped as to how to resolve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Python easy\_install not working on my Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012246/why-is-python-easy-install-not-working-on-my-mac)

Comment: permission denied?

Answer (score 9):

You seem to have a version conflict; note the `setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg` path, but the `/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7` script wants to load `0.6c12dev-r88846` instead.

The latter is a development version; it has the revision number of a subversion repository embedded in the version (`dev-r88846`).

I suspect you have *two* python installations; one is the system version (in `/System/Library` and the other is installed with the python installer into `/Library/`, and the stub script in `/usr/bin/` may be installed with the system python.

If so, there'll be another copy of the stub at `/Library/Python/2.7/bin/easy_install-2.7`, which should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I get what your saying though I am still unsure how to fix it exactly. I checked the two locations you suggested for the python installs. There is nothing in the /System/Library but under /Library/Python there appear to be multiple versions (2.3, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7). I am also unsure how to make the system use one stub over another.

Comment: The system python location is `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current`. I *believe* that the /Library/Python` locations are just the `site-packages` locations for the system pythons; I am not certain now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, eventually ended up running the 2.7.3 easy_install by
/opt/python2.7.3/bin/easy_install which worked fine