# ReviewBoard installation on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, review-board

I'm trying to install ReviewBoard on ubuntu 12.04 using easy_install.

http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.7/admin/installation/linux/

I tried above instruction step by step, but stucked in `easy_install ReviewBoard`

Error message is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('distribute', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.8-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 378, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.8-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2565, in load_entry_point
    raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'easy_install') not found
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858779/easy-install-importerror-entry-point-console-scripts-easy-install-not). If there is no way to fixing it, reinstall it. Refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012246/why-is-python-easy-install-not-working-on-my-mac).

Answer (score 3):

I got the exact same error trying to upgrade reviewboard. It seems distribute and setuptools are clashing.

I fixed it by simply removing the distribute egg like this:

```
$ sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute*
```