# Pip: ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'pip') not found

Tags: python, pip

I install pip with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools, python-pip
```

But when I try install something with pip i have this error

```
sudo pip install Flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
  load_entry_point('pip==1.3.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 378, in    load_entry_point
  return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2565, in load_entry_point
  raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'pip') not found
```

why?? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858779/easy-install-importerror-entry-point-console-scripts-easy-install-not

Does this link help you ?

Comment: I have two version of setuptools (0.9.4 and 0.9.5) How I can Uninstall one of them?

Comment: permission denied?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I remove setuptools 0.9.4 and do 'pip install --upgrade setuptools' and work good.

Comment: How did you used pip to upgrade setuptools if you can't run pip?

Answer (score 18):

`sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`

may do the trick. Try it

Comment: I had the same issue. This helped!

Comment: legend! I was trying to realise what was going on for 2 hours. :D

Answer (score 1):

you may check the /usr/bin/pip file, if it links to pip2, then change the first line of pip2 from '/usr/bin/python' to '/usr/bin/python2.7' or '/usr/bin/python2.x' matching pip2. If it links to pip3, then change to python3 or the version python3.x matching pip3.

It works for me because I have installed python 2.7 and 3 so and pip. So when I use 'pip' it using python3 as default, which resulting in the same output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: In latest systems where by default python3 is installed, this helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing almost same error and having python2.7 installed on my mac.
I tried `sudo python2.7 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip` and it worked for me.
If you have python3 installed then you can try `sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`
Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I find there are multiple version pip on my Ubuntu,I followed these steps and it worked:

1. `sudo apt-get remove python-pip`
2. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/pip-2.7 sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/pip`
3. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.4.1.egg-info`
4. `sudo easy_install -m pip-2.7 sudo easy_install -m pip`
5. `curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py`
6. `sudo python get-pip.py`

Comment: Thanks, your idea gave me the idea to remove the pip folders in my /usr/local/lib/python3.10 which fixed my similar issues!