# Pip Error- ImportError

Tags: python, unix, pip

When I run pip on my terminal I get the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2220, in load_entry_point
raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'pip') not found
```

I know that this issue has been raised before in stack overflow, but no thread addresses what I should do exactly.

Comment: did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427486/pip-importerror-entry-point-console-scripts-pip-not-found

Comment: How did you install pip? Thinks in /usr/local/bin are not installed by Apple whilst things in /System are

Comment: @Guy unlikely as the /System paths imply this is OSX

Comment: I don't know how to view what setuptools I have so I'm not sure if that is my problem.
I have tried pip install --upgrade setuptools and nothing changed. @Guy

Comment: I installed pip multiple ways and I think this is my problem, don't know what to remove though