# pip installation error when installing a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

So, I'm currently trying to install this package:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@async
```

Github here: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py

but I get this error:

```
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-khtOce/aiohttp/setup.py", line 61, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("aiohttp requires Python 3.4.1+")
RuntimeError: aiohttp requires Python 3.4.1+

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-khtOce/aiohttp/
```

So instead I have tried using pip3 to install the same package, but I'm currently getting a version conflict which I do not know how to solve.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==8.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.14-  py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 305, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2243, in load_entry_point
raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'pip3') not found
```

I remember doing this yesterday, and I may have toyed around installing and reinstalling pip, but before, when I tried to install the same package when pip3 was working, I still remember getting the same error, so idk if solving the version conflict will do much.

Comment: Might want to look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427486/pip-importerror-entry-point-console-scripts-pip-not-found

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a setuptools conflict here which will probably be resolved by updating setuptools.

Try:

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

You can remove the previous setuptools installation in case it gives you a problem.

Comment: WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f10cef3ad50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/pip/.  Your solution immediately resolves it. setuptools from 65.5->69.1 resolved