# python package installing for novices

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, package, nose

i'm learning python from on online book and have come to the stage where the author asks the reader to install pip, virtualenv, nose, and distribute. to make it fun, he asks the reader to figure out how :-)
well, i'm an utter novice and have spent the last week trying to figure that out 
on the basis of recommendation i found, i've downloaded homebrew and tried to use pip (sudo easy_install). it runs ok and says something about finishing processing dependencies. 
yet when i try nosetests, i get a 'command not found'.

Edit - Zmo, i tried what you suggested and this is the result. thanks for your help.

unknown-00-25-00-47-cc-3d:~ k$ sudo /usr/bin/easy_install pip
Password:
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.5.4
Processing pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg
pip 1.5.4 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
unknown-00-25-00-47-cc-3d:~ k$ sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install nosetests
Downloading/unpacking nosetests
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement nosetests
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for nosetests
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/k/Library/Logs/pip.log

I have two requests for the community:
1) can someone help me solve this specific problem? (i use a 2009 mac with mavericks) and 
2) can someone point me in the direction of some resources online where an utter novice like myself can learn about packages for python? (every resource i see assumes some level of knowledge, which i don't have).

thanks in advance,
K.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're having? I would recommend listing all of the commands you ran when attempting to create the virtualenv, activate it, install something using pip, and then finally run nosetests.

Comment: you can try the first answer of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012246/why-is-python-easy-install-not-working-on-my-mac

Comment: if you want help, you should first give the most important thing for your question, which what are the "*something about finishing processing dependencies*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend going through the tutorial and installing first "easy Install" http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html and then install pip and the rest of the items with it.

Also you can follow the tutorial on (http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html ) after that everything will be installed with pip itself.

PS: This question also can be useful ([What is the most compatible way to install python modules on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213690/what-is-the-most-compatible-way-to-install-python-modules-on-a-mac))

Answer (score 0):

anyway, as you're on OSX 10.9, run exactly what follows in the terminal:

```
sudo /usr/bin/easy_install pip
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install nosetests
```

if you get errors here, please copy/paste them in your question as an edit

```
/usr/local/bin/nosetests
```

for the resources, please refer to leonardo's links, all I'd do is copy/paste them here (or do the same *duckducking* as he did).