# Updating pip and setuptools in homebrew does not work

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

After `brew install python`, the following comes up:

```
Pip and setuptools have been installed. To update them
  pip2 install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

Running pip2 install

```
pip2 install --upgrade pip setuptools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip2", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip2')()
  File "/Users/user1/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 564, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Users/user1/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2661, in load_entry_point
    raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group, name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'pip2') not found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [homebrew pip install jupyter error: ImportError: Entry point ('console\_scripts', 'pip2') not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495954/homebrew-pip-install-jupyter-error-importerror-entry-point-console-scripts)

Answer (score 13):

I was running into this after upgrading from Python 2.7.13 to 2.7.14 using Homebrew. I used the suggestion found in this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/739 and it worked for me. The actual command I ran was:

`/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/bin/python2 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`

Good luck.