# AssertionError while run zc.buildout

Tags: django, buildout

I have an issue in work with buildout. I download bootstrap.py using ,

```
wget http://downloads.buildout.org/2/bootstrap.py
```

buildout.cfg

```
[buildout]
parts = python
        django
develop = .
eggs = beautifulsoup
       .....

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
wsgi = true
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
```

when I try **./bin/buildout**.
I got the following error.

```
Upgraded:
  distribute version 0.6.35;
restarting.
Generated script '/home/tests/myproject/bin/buildout'.
Develop: '/home/tests/myproject/.'
While:
  Installing.
  Processing develop directory '/home/tests/myproject/.'.

An internal error occured due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tests/myproject/eggs/zc.buildout-2.0.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1808, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/home/tests/myproject/eggs/zc.buildout-2.0.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 468, in install
    installed_develop_eggs = self._develop()
  File "/home/tests/myproject/eggs/zc.buildout-2.0.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 709, in _develop
    zc.buildout.easy_install.develop(setup, dest)
  File "/home/tests/myproject/eggs/zc.buildout-2.0.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 862, in develop
    return _copyeggs(tmp3, dest, '.egg-link', undo)
  File "/home/tests//eggs/zc.buildout-2.0.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 803, in _copyeggs
    assert len(result) == 1, str(result)
AssertionError: []
```

Can any one help me to resolve it.

Comment: Have you tried `http://downloads.buildout.org/1/bootstrap.py`? It could be that the `django` recipe is not (yet) ready for Buildout 2.0.

Comment: I try the older bootstrap.py ,Npow I got the error

Comment: continue    # try the next older version of project
  File "/home/tests/fridaycloud.aws/eggs/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve

Comment: the buildout in my system is 2.0.1

Comment: if I install buildout 2.0.0 ,solves the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You really want to run this with a virtualenv setup; on a package-based OS (such as Debian, Ubuntu, RedHat, etc) you easily run into conflicts between system-installed versions of distribute, easy_install and other 3rd-party packages, and what a buildout requires (see http://workaround.org/easy-install-debian for an explanation as to why).

Comment: File "./bin/buildout", line 17, in <module>
    import zc.buildout.buildout
  File "/home/tests/fridaycloud.aws/eggs/zc.buildout-1.7.0-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 40, in <module>
    import zc.buildout.download

Comment: File "/home/tests/fridaycloud.aws/eggs/zc.buildout-1.7.0-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/download.py", line 20, in <module>
    from zc.buildout.easy_install import realpath
  File "/home/tests/fridaycloud.aws/eggs/zc.buildout-1.7.0-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 31, in <module>
    import setuptools.package_index

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/package_index.py", line 158, in <module>

Comment: @Jisson: I reproduced your problem with the 2.0.x line in a virtual environment. I then switched to the 1.x branch and things worked fine.

Comment: sys.version[:3], require('distribute')[0].version
  File "/home/tests/fridaycloud.aws/eggs/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    continue    # try the next older version of project

Comment: @Jisson: *Please* use a pastie (pastie.org) or similar to give me a traceback, or edit your question perhaps. Comments are not suitable for this.

Comment: That traceback is incomplete. All I see is code comments on certain lines, I do *not* see an exception.

Comment: @Jisson: I'm afraid that's a local problem, see [Easy_install and Pip doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7110360) Try deleting `/home/tests/fridaycloud.aws/eggs/setuptools*` and `/home/tests/fridaycloud.aws/eggs/distribute*`.

Comment: @Jisson: Moral of the story: always use a virtualenv if you can: http://workaround.org/easy-install-debian

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters   Thank you for your valuable comments,please keep in touch .Thanks a lot

Comment: @Jisson: Just to summarize: you have two *separate* problems. The first is that `djangorecipe` only works with Buildout 1.x. This is also Buildout's fault for not being as backwards compatible as it perhaps could be. The other is that mixing Distribute versions on a package-based system often goes wrong, which can be solved using a virtual env.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24833/discussion-between-jisson-and-martijn-pieters)

Comment: @MartijnPieters ehm, I've got some 10 buildouts locally that are 2.0 *and* that use djangorecipe. Djangorecipe 1.5 (released a month ago) fixed the incompatibility.

Comment: @ReinoutvanRees: Interesting; I tried it in a virtual env and got a similar error to the OP.

Comment: @ReinoutvanRees: Yay for intermittend failures! It works now. Perhaps my egg cache got in the way somewhere.

Comment: Tnx, I see you removed the "djangorecipe doesn't work" part :-)

Comment: @ReinoutvanRees: AH! Misread the error message, missed a timeout! The recipe never even made it to my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here not buildout, but setuptools: it was forked into distribute and setuptools, then the reunion of both, the further development. Future looks good for setuptools. But ghosts of the past are still hunting us.

[Download a bootstrap.py fetching the latest setuptools](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jensens/9226657/raw/f78186f55ee9536af0a5ce2a9a7617a7dde53d28/bootstrap.py)

Pin zc.buildout to >= 2.2.1 and setuptools to >= 2.2 - add a versions section to buildout.cfg:

```
[versions]
zc.buildout = >= 2.2.1
setuptools = >= 2.2
```

Use with virtualenv >=1.9.1 with parameter `--no-setuptools` So run:

```
virtualenv --no-setuptools env
./env/bin/python bootstrap.py
./bin/buildout
```